# ReactJS & Google MDL Button onClick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I have some JS like below. I find that if I remove `mdl-js-layout` the `onClick` of the button works. Otherwise it fails. Why might this be? I have already did `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log('update')
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  },

  addExpense: function() {
    console.log('add expense');
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div ref="appLayout" className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
        <div className="mdl-layout__drawer">
          <span className="mdl-layout-title">Expenses</span>
          <nav className="mdl-navigation">
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Expenses</a>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <main className="mdl-layout__content">
          <div className="page-content">
            <div className="mdl-grid">
              <div className="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <button ref="btnAddExpense" onClick={this.addExpense} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--accent">
                  Add Expense
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

If I look into the React debugger tools, I can actually see the onClick is supposed to be bound?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl/issues/254 - you might find this helpful; Make sure the click handler is a closure with the correct 'this' object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like mdl is not compatible with react, and prevents the click events from the react component from working.  Hopefully, this would be fixed in a future update, but until then, you can work around this by manually re-adding the events after mounting the component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  var button = this.refs.btnAddExpense;
  button.addEventListener('click', this.addExpense);
},
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6qn62b1s/)

Comment: Agreed React uses dynamic templating so it is necessary to upgrade the element. There is also a react-mdl project which handles some other issues. As per http://dragablz.net/2015/07/14/react-js-and-material-design-lite/, componentHandler.upgradeElement() might be a bit lighter than upgradeDom(). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fignooton88/2eLuub5w/5/) answers your question:
With the resources used it apparently does not need to touch the DOM.

```
HTML
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js">
</script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

JS
var Widget = React.createClass({
  handleBtnClick: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked!");
    return true;
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div >
      <form>
        < button className = "mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-textfield--full-width mdl-button--facebook"
          onClick = {
            this.handleBtnClick
          } >
          Click MEEEEEE!
        < /button >  </form> < /div >;
     }
  });

  ReactDOM.render( < Widget / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I find that its not working when `mdl-js-layout` is used

Comment: yes.. look at the react-mdl project to address that.

Comment: it is perhaps like throwing an atom bomb at an ant hill in this case, but react and mdl are rapidly evolving frameworks from companies with vast resources so hopefully the react-mdl project acts as a collection point for incompatibilities that arise.